# iTunes - Issue with EPF importer

Tags: python, itunes

I'm having an issue with my first iTunes EPF import, the setup seemed to have gone OK going through their guide until I have tried my first data import, which gives the following output:

```
root@services:/var/www/html/epf# ./EPFImporter.py /var/www/html/epf/collection/itunes20180124/
2018-03-02 16:26:02,255 [INFO]: Beginning import for the following directories:
    /var/www/html/epf/collection/itunes20180124/
2018-03-02 16:26:02,256 [INFO]: Importing files in /var/www/html/epf/collection/itunes20180124/
2018-03-02 16:26:02,257 [INFO]: Starting import of /var/www/html/epf/collection/itunes20180124...
2018-03-02 16:26:02,258 [INFO]: Beginning full ingest of epf_collection (7682010 records)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./EPFImporter.py", line 452, in <module>
    main()
  File "./EPFImporter.py", line 435, in main
    fieldDelim=fieldSep)
  File "./EPFImporter.py", line 220, in doImport
    ing.ingest(skipKeyViolators=skipKeyViolators)
  File "/var/www/html/epf/EPFIngester.py", line 113, in ingest
    self.ingestFull(skipKeyViolators=skipKeyViolators)
  File "/var/www/html/epf/EPFIngester.py", line 128, in ingestFull
    self._createTable(self.tmpTableName)
  File "/var/www/html/epf/EPFIngester.py", line 299, in _createTable
    cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s""" % tableName)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 253, in execute
    self._warning_check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 155, in _warning_check
    warn(self.Warning(*w[1:3]), stacklevel=3)
_mysql_exceptions.Warning: (1051L, u"Unknown table 'epf.epf_collection_tmp'")
root@services:/var/www/html/epf#
```

The log file seems OK with nothing for me to really go on:

```
2018-03-02 16:23:11,336 [INFO]: Beginning import for the following directories:
    /var/www/html/epf/collection/itunes20180124/
2018-03-02 16:23:11,337 [INFO]: Importing files in /var/www/html/epf/collection/itunes20180124/
2018-03-02 16:23:11,338 [INFO]: Starting import of /var/www/html/epf/collection/itunes20180124...
2018-03-02 16:23:11,339 [INFO]: Beginning full ingest of epf_collection (7682010 records)
```

It looks like it can read the file OK because it knows how many records are contained within it). Unfortunately I know virtually nothing about python so I'm a little lost. I can see that there is a warning in the last line, but I really don't know what to do about it.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue Apple are aware of, potentially not something I was doing wrong, hopefully this will help someone.

*Hi,
Thank you for your inquiry regarding the EPF. Please rest assured this issue you've noted is being actively worked on by our tools and product support team. Once we have an update from this team, we will reach out immediately to notify you. Your patience and understanding is greatly appreciated.
Regards,
The Affiliate Program team*

I had this back when I asked what the ETA was to resolve:

*Hi,
Thank you for your inquiry. I understand your frustration with the EPF issues. We have escalated this to our engineering department and will provide an update once we have information. At this time we do not have an ETA for when it will functional.
To answer your second question, we don't have a way to increase the limit for the Search API because of its infrastructure and backend setup. Again, we are working to resolve the EPF issues as soon as we can and once it is resolved, we will provide an update. Thank you for your patience.*

Answer (score 0):

MySQLdb turns MySQL warnings into python warnings and for some reason the default in EPFIngester.py is to treat warnings as errors. You can get around this by **commenting out line 56** in **EPFImporter.py**.

`warnings.filterwarnings('error')`

`# warnings.filterwarnings('error')`